# Number of addresses in a memory region

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

So I am looking at some Operating Systems exercises and we have

> A swapping system eliminates holes by compaction. Assuming a
>              random distribution of many holes and many data segments and a 
>              time to read or write a 32-bit memory word of 10 nsec, about how 
>              long does it take to compact 128 MB? For simplicity, assume that 
>              word 0 is part of a hole and that the highest word in memory
>              contains valid data.
>
> The solution is : `128 x 2^20 / 4 = 2^25` memory address
>
> ```
>       compaction time = (read + write) * # of memory access
>                       = 2 x 10 x 10 ^ -9 x 2^25
>                       = 671 ms
> ```

Problem is I dont understand the `128 x 2^20 / 4 = 2^25 memory address` part ? How did we get 2^20 in this case? I gues the 4 is 4 bytes =32 bits so I kinda understand that.

Now in `2 x 10 x 10 ^ -9 x 2^25` what is 2 here?

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A megabyte is $2^{20}$ bytes.

The factor of $2$ is because we need to count both reads and writes.

Comment: Sorry but a megabyte is 1024 bytes which is 2^10 bytes..why 2^20 bytes?

Comment: No, a kilobyte is $2^{10}$ bytes. A megabyte is $2^{20}$ bytes, a gigabyte is $2^{30}$ bytes, a terabyte is $2^{40}$ bytes, and a petabyte is $2^{50}$ bytes. All of this information can be found online. Please make more effort next time. When something doesn't make sense, sometimes there is an error, and at other times the mistake is yours. In cases like this it is very easy to find out. No need to trouble us here.

Comment: See [the table on the top right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) for the source of the confusion.